# Using WebBrowser to download prompted file while retaining signed in session

Tags: c#, iframe, browser

Overview:
I am building an application using Visual Studios' WebBrowser, and this application needs to download a file once it logs into the site.

Originally I thought the events were not firing but they were. The actual issue is downloading a file while retaining the session cookies. Originally I was trying to download the file by using WebClient, in the navigating event of the WebBrowser.

The issue is that this site, has an iframe, and it posts data using that iframe in order to create the download dialog.

So basically the download URL, loads a page, then after about 5 seconds or so, it will run some javascript with session cookies and other data, and post to a download URL, which will be fired inside an iframe in the page, and the user will be prompted to download the file.

How do I tap into the normal web browser downloading? Can i override how the prompt comes up? Instead of prompting the user, i can just set a path to where i want the file to be stored, and the name of the file.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, makes sense ill be more careful in the future